# ionic firebase.getToken() always return null on android API 23 6.0.0 but not in other version android

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework

why firebase.getToken() always return null on android API 23 6.0.0 but not in other version android? I tried on android nougat, oreo, marsh(6.0.1), version before 23 is not null, only on android 6.0.0

Note :  I'm using plugin cordova-plugin-firebase 1.0.5 (https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase)
I'm run to emulator genymotion

the code

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {      
  // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
  // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
  var idtoken: string;

  if(this.platform.is('core') || this.platform.is('mobileweb')) {

  }else {
    this.firebase.getToken().then(token => {
        idtoken = token;
        alert(token)
     }) // save the token server-side and use it to push notifications to this device
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error getting token', error)
     });
    this.firebase.onTokenRefresh().subscribe((token: string) => {
        idtoken = token;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: any error showing in console ?

Comment: this may helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46583560/ionic-firebase-token-alway-null-and-no-token-refresh

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki no error, only null token.. I don't think so with that link, because firebase working normally on other android version.. token null only on android 6.0.0

Comment: @E-Place And if you try to use getIdToken() instead of getToken()?

Comment: @LeonardoGabriel there no method `getIdToken()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run to emulator, please make sure you install google play service at your emulator

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for hinting us in the correct direction @Eggy Sudianto.

The problem for us was that our rooted device does not even have *google play services* which means the plugin worked but no token was ever received. Switching device actually solved the problem for us.